# Service Bus Explorer - Unable to see messages on Subscription Topic when added rule/filer

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

Service Bus Explorer - Unable to see messages on Subscription Topic when added rule/filer.

**Following is a message being generated on bus;**

```
{
  "header": {
    "Major": 1,
    "Minor": 0,
    "Patch": 0,
    "MessageType": "EmployeeMessage",
  },
  "message": "message text"
}
```

I have created two subscriptions;

1. All - with rule as `"1=1"`
   In this subscription I get all the messages.
2. MessageType - here rule is `MessageType="EmployeeMessage"`
   In this, I am expecting messages with `MessageType` as `EmployeeMessage`. But I am not getting single message in this subscription.

[image]
Can some help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Topic Subscription validates the Rule against the message custom properties (headers)

If you send the right set of custom properties with the message, it gets validated and get into the Subscription.

The problem might be with the message, that is sent to the Topic. Please try to receive the message in `All` Subscription through Service Bus Explorer and check whether the required custom property is available in it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I am able to receive the message in All subscription, and it has required Custom property, but the message is not received in MessageType subscription.

Comment: Can you provide the screen shot of the message received in Service Bus Explorer?